# Is it possible to embed an Angular5 app in a classic website?

Tags: angular, embed

I have written a web application in Angular5 (stored on an AWS S3 cloud).

Another company, with a traditionnal website want to embed a page of my web application in their website (for example, in an iframe).

Is it possible ?

How can I do that ?

Comment: What's wrong with iframe then?

Comment: `<iframe src"https://www.your-angular-app.com"></iframe>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions to your problem:

- Use an oldschool `iframe`. Nothing wrong with that:

  `<iframe src="https://www.yourUrl.com"></iframe>`
- Angular Elements. This project is based on the WebComponents spec and enables the compilation of Angular applications into custom html-tags. Check out [this excellent blog post on the topic](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-elements-a-practical-introduction-to-web-components-with-angular-6-52c0b3076c2c) or the respective [Angular Elements documentation](https://angular.io/guide/elements).

Additional considerations:

#### CORS

One thing you might want to consider in the case of `iframe` is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), you'll have to manually allow the other companies website to include your application in your [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) Header.

#### Bandwidth:

Allowing another website to embed your application in an `iframe` will put the burden of the additional traffic on your server.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm.

Comment: Good all fashion iframe